# Force native taxonomy-term pages to only show <H1> and not all content

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms

How do I force taxonomy term pages to show only the `<h1>` part and not all the nodes associated with that term?

I could use a view for that, but I am trying to change the taxonomy term pages without using the Views module.

Comment: template files is probably the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override the default listing with the built-in view, see here https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/165052/3218

To only show the title you then need to adapt the view:

- go to the view's edit page (admin/structure/views/view/taxonomy_term/edit)
- change the format-display from rendered entity, to fields
- remove all fields and add the title field as only field