# How do I overwrite the view output for each vocabulary?

Tags: views, 8, taxonomy-terms

This is the Drupal 8 version of the following question: [How do I override a taxonomy/term/% list with a view?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/27682/how-do-i-override-a-taxonomy-term-list-with-a-view)

In short: You can edit the default, global taxonomy/term/% view, but you can not set custom taxonomy view. For example, /my-custom-category/% will show the default, global view output (not the customized one).

As you can see, the most elegant solution for Drupal 7 was using the *Taxonomy Display* module. However, it hasn't been ported.

How would you tackle this problem in Drupal 8?

Comment: Disable the default view?

Comment: @NoSssweat Unfortunately, this seems to work only if no term id is given. So /products/ would display my view, but /products/14 would display just a blank content area (while displaying term name in <title>).

P.S. Thanks for editing my post.

Comment: how is your contextual filter set up?

Comment: @NoSssweat I guess I tried to use the same ones as default core taxonomy term view used. However, it seems that I have found the solution  - a module called "Taxonomy Views Integrator" which provides with the needed functionality (I posted it as answer).

Answer (score 3):

Ok, it seems that I have found a solution. A Drupal 8 & 7 module called "Taxonomy Views Integrator" provides ability to set custom view for each vocabulary and/or terms. So far seems to work fine. Link to module - https://www.drupal.org/project/tvi