# How can i use taxonomy name in url page using a view

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms

I have a taxonomy terms like:

- christmas
- wedding

How can I build a view with url page like this: `www.site.com/%` 
being `%` christmas or wedding,

If users go to  `www.site.com/christmas` just display nodes with christmas taxonomy.

If users go to  `www.site.com/wedding` just display nodes with wedding taxonomy.

I have to do `n` views with same fields that why I want to do just one generic view.

Comment: Why not just use pathauto and make the aliasing rule [term-name] or whatever the appropriate token is? Also, you can create one view and tell vocab + vocab terms to use that view or views with a module like TVI.

Answer (score 1):

The [PathAuto module](https://www.drupal.org/project/pathauto) allows you to easily change the URLs for the default taxonomy listings (which do what you describe).

Install the module and go to Administration > Configuration > Search and metadata > URL aliases.

You can set a pattern for your vocabulary that is just `[term:name]` BUT [there are good reasons not to do that](https://www.drupal.org/node/73232) (for example if a category overlaps with a default path).  Something like `holiday/[term:name]` is likely a better choice.

For more options on PathAuto see the [recipes from Drupal.org](https://www.drupal.org/node/124462).

If you need more control over the display you can [override the view that generates term pages.](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/165052/210)

Comment: Seconded, you _can_ do this but generally you should stick to [vocab-name]/[term-name] as a default alias as acrosman said. Views still work off of taxonomy/term/% path since it is a system path, and you can use someting like TVI to enhance the display of different vocabularies by using rendered entities instead of node fields.